# Queue Options in Mule Cloudhub

Tags: mule, mq, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

I wanted to use queueing in my Mule applications deployed on cloudhub.
what are the options available?

As per my learning I think if we add VM component then we will be able to see the queue in cloudhub persistence queue option.

I have seen Anypoint MQ connectors as well..

are these two options are same?

If not, then which one is better?

Any other options??

Answer (score 0):

VM queues are very basic point-to-point queues. You won't be able to browse the queue, access it through apis, use publish-subcribe, app to app, org to org and others.

For any non basic point-to-point use case, consider Anypoint MQ. Otherwise, any other cloud messaging solution could be used too if it has the appropriate connector.

Answer (score 0):

use anypoint MQ, its easier to config with client. i suggest anypoint MQ becuz of pub/sub msgs